# I am unable to click on hyperlink of my web page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Blocked Local Queues
`
could you lz provide me the solution here to click on hyperlink using selenium webdriver.

HTML code:

```
   <tr> <td width="3%"></td> <td width="97%">Event Processing Status <table class="table1" width="100%"> <tbody><tr> <td width="3%"></td> <td width="97%"><a href="blockedLocalUsers.jsp"target="right">Blocked Local Queues</a></td></tr> <tr> <td width="3%"></td> <td width="97%"><a href="blockedRemoteUsers.jsp" target="right">Blocked Remote Queues</a> </td></tr> </tbody></table> </td></tr>
```

code:

```
public class XPDMGatewayAdminPage { public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("aws-edgetc01:8080/XPDMGateway/admin/"); 

    driver.manage().window().maximize(); 

    driver.findElement(By.name("btnLogin")).click();

    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,40); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/ta
ble/tbody/tr[13]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a"))); 

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td/a[@href='blockedLocalUsers.jsp' and text()='Blocked Local Queues']")).click(); 
}
```

Comment: <pre>
    <a href="blockedLocalUsers.jsp" target="right">Blocked Local Queues</a>
</pre>

Comment: Please provide more context

Comment: Please read why a [**`Can someone help me? not an actual question?`**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: below is my html code, <td width="97%"

 <a href="blockedLocalUsers.jsp" target="right">Blocked Local Queues</a>
 </td>  send me the xpath so that I can click on hyperlink,I have tried  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Blocked Local Queues']")).click(); but did not get sucess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this xpath : `//a[text()="Blocked Local Queues"]`

Comment: it is giving me exception Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[text()='Blocked Local Queues']"}
Command duration or timeout: 15 milliseconds

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Blocked Local Queues']")).click();

Comment: is no one expert here to get it out from this troubleshoot?

Comment: can you share your link .try this then  //td/a[@href='blockedLocalUsers.jsp' and text()='Blocked Local Queues']

Comment: this is also not working,Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//td/a[@href='blockedLocalUsers.jsp' and text()='Blocked Local Queues']"}
Command duration or timeout: 16 milliseconds

Comment: try to add wait before clicking event and can you share more html code please confm element is not inside any iframe

Comment: WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,40);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[13]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a")));
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td/a[@href='blockedLocalUsers.jsp' and text()='Blocked Local Queues']")).click();

Comment: webelement Inside any iframe ? can you please share more html code with below code it's not possible to tell

Comment: <tr>
<td width="3%"></td>
<td width="97%">Event Processing Status
<table class="table1" width="100%">
<tbody><tr>
<td width="3%"></td>
<td width="97%"><a href="blockedLocalUsers.jsp"target="right">Blocked Local Queues</a></td></tr>
<tr>
<td width="3%"></td>
<td width="97%"><a href="blockedRemoteUsers.jsp" target="right">Blocked Remote Queues</a>
</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
</td></tr>

Comment: And do share your code what you have try may be issue in your code

Comment: public class XPDMGatewayAdminPage {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();driver.get("http://aws-edgetc01:8080/XPDMGateway/admin/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.name("btnLogin")).click();
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,40);  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[13]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td/a[@href='blockedLocalUsers.jsp' and text()='Blocked Local Queues']")).click();
 }
}

Comment: Can you try to add hard wait before clicking like thread.sleep();

Comment: I have used explicit wait but still did not get succeed

Answer (score 0):

you can try linkText:

```
WebElement MyAccountLink = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Blocked Local Queues"));
MyAccountLink.click();
```

Hope it works.

Comment: it's not xpath, it's linkText did you try it? @user7424603